# Formatting an outputText value field in HTML (VF Page)

Tags: visualforce, html5

I have a VF Page with apex tags and have to transform it in HTML to adapt for Salesforce1. With apex I was able to format a text field as number and get only 2 decimals:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!LBo}" var="o" style="width:300px" >
    <apex:column headerValue="My Annual Leave Balance : ">
        <apex:outputText value="{0, number, #0.00}">           
            <apex:param value="{!VALUE(o.Units__c)}"/>
        </apex:outputText>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="No of Days : ">
        <apex:outputText value="{0, number, #0.00}">
            <apex:param value="{!VALUE(o.Units__c)/7.5}"/>
        </apex:outputText>
    </apex:column>           
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

How can I get the same formating in HTML?

```
<table class="table" value="{!LBo}" var="o">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>My Annual Leave Balance</th>
            <th>No of Days</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <apex:repeat value="{!LBo}" var="o">
            <tr> 
                <td>{!VALUE(o.Units__c}</td>
                <td>{!VALUE(o.Units__c)/7.5}</td>                        
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Does `ROUND(number, num_digits)` not suit your needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using the `ROUND(number, num_digits)` function. From the `Visualforce Developer Guide` on [Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm):

> **Function**
> `ROUND`
>
> **Description**
> Returns the nearest number to a number you specify, constraining the new number by a specified number of digits.
>
> **Use**
> `ROUND(number, num_digits)` and replace `number` with the field or expression you want rounded; replace `num_digits` with the number of decimal places you want to consider when rounding.

In this case, you need:

```
<td>{!ROUND(VALUE(o.Units__c), 2)}</td>
<td>{!ROUND(VALUE(o.Units__c)/7.5, 2)}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think of writing this kind of logic upon injecting javacript:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!LBo}" var="o">
<tr> 
<td>{!VALUE(o.Units__c}</td>                
<script>
    var num = '{!VALUE(o.Units__c)/7.5}';
    var n = num.toFixed(2);
    document.write("<td>" + n + "</td>");
</script>           
</tr>
</apex:repeat>
```